# CSS: Make one td smaller than other td of a table

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table like this

```
   <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th colspan="2"><label>Label</label></th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="draggable odd">
          <td class="field-multiple-drag">
            <a href="#" class="tabledrag-handle" title="Drag to re-order">
              <div class="handle">&nbsp;</div>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="content">
            <div>
              Content
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Please note the header, it is 2 colspan header.

I want the first td of the tbody should be smaller than the 2nd td as it has only an icon and it is occupying the same space as the other td.

I have tried the following css but it did not work for me.

```
table {
  width: 100%
}

td.field-multiple-drag {
  width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td.content {
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: So what about it is not working? https://jsfiddle.net/bjna9cty/ looks fine to me (tested in Chrome).

Comment: Could you add `display: inline-block` to `td.field-multiple-drag`?

Answer (score 0):

I have change your code

from

```
td.field-multiple-drag {
  width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

to

```
    td.field-multiple-drag {
    width: 10%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helps you

**Html**

```
<table class="fixed">
<tr>
    <td>
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 256 256" height="512" viewBox="0 0 256 256" width="512"><path d="m21.524 12.884c-.435 0-.851-.069-1.255-.17l-16.485 24.496h31.054l12.277-24.327h-25.591z" fill="#fcac27"/><path d="m47.115 12.884-12.277 24.326h31.054l8.185-24.326z" fill="#fc3850"/><path d="m74.077 12.884-8.185 24.326h31.054l4.092-24.326z" fill="#fcac27"/><path d="m101.038 12.884-4.092 24.326h31.054v-24.326z" fill="#fc3850"/><path d="m128 12.884v24.326h31.054l-4.092-24.326z" fill="#fcac27"/><path d="m154.962 12.884 4.092 24.326h31.054l-8.185-24.326z" fill="#fc3850"/><path d="m181.923 12.884 8.185 24.326h31.054l-12.277-24.326z" fill="#fcac27"/><path d="m235.55 12.444h-.036c-.638.28-1.339.44-2.08.44h-24.55l12.277 24.327h31.054z" fill="#fc3850"/><path d="m233.435 2.502h-211.911c-2.867 0-5.191 2.324-5.191 5.191 0 2.867 2.324 5.191 5.191 5.191h211.911c2.867 0 5.191-2.324 5.191-5.191 0-2.867-2.324-5.191-5.191-5.191z" fill="#c5e3ff"/><path d="m233.435 15.384h-211.912c-4.24 0-7.69-3.45-7.69-7.69 0-4.241 3.45-7.691 7.69-7.691h211.911c4.241 0 7.691 3.45 7.691 7.691.001 4.24-3.449 7.69-7.69 7.69zm-211.912-10.382c-1.483 0-2.69 1.207-2.69 2.691 0 1.483 1.207 2.69 2.69 2.69h211.911c1.484 0 2.691-1.207 2.691-2.69 0-1.484-1.207-2.691-2.691-2.691z"/><path d="m236.689 69.435c-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527 0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527 0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527 0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527s-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527c0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527s-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527c0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527 0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527 0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527-2.826 0-5.468-.767-7.751-2.086v134.044c0 6.436 5.236 11.672 11.672 11.672h208.494c6.436 0 11.672-5.236 11.672-11.672v-133.499c-2.033.978-4.302 1.541-6.709 1.541z" fill="#2a4a97"/><path d="m165.729 243.116h-76.5c-2.867 0-5.191 2.324-5.191 5.191 0 2.867 2.324 5.191 5.191 5.191h76.5c2.867 0 5.191-2.324 5.191-5.191.001-2.867-2.324-5.191-5.191-5.191z" fill="#c5e3ff"/><path d="m101.686 213.065h51.586v30.051h-51.586z" fill="#94bdea"/><path d="m11.56 182.731v18.662c0 6.436 5.236 11.672 11.672 11.672h208.494c6.436 0 11.672-5.236 11.672-11.672v-18.662z" fill="#c5e3ff"/><circle cx="127.479" cy="197.367" fill="#94bdea" r="5.191"/><path d="m221.162 53.908c0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527 0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527 0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527s-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527c0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527s-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527c0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527 0 8.575-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527 0 7.597-5.459 13.909-12.667 15.253v113.57h210.616v-113.81c-6.683-1.733-11.625-7.788-11.625-15.013z" fill="#edf4fc"/><path d="m164.664 105.156-25.505 9.115c-.432.15-.821.406-1.13.743l-20.094 21.92c-.846.923-2.207 1.163-3.318.583l-19.701-10.279c-.876-.457-1.93-.412-2.763.119l-19.405 12.349c-.78.496-1.755.57-2.601.197l-15.647-6.903v23.874h112v-50.424c0-.95-.941-1.614-1.836-1.294z" fill="#1387ce"/><g fill="#45bdf0"><path d="m164.664 105.156-8.375 2.993v48.725h10.211v-50.424c0-.95-.941-1.614-1.836-1.294z"/><path d="m144.17 112.48-5.012 1.791c-.432.15-.821.406-1.13.743l-4.241 4.626v37.234h10.382v-44.394z"/><path d="m121.67 132.859-3.735 4.075c-.846.923-2.207 1.163-3.318.583l-3.329-1.737v21.093h10.382z"/><path d="m99.17 129.458-4.254-2.22c-.876-.457-1.93-.412-2.763.119l-3.364 2.141v27.375h10.381z"/><path d="m76.67 137.21-3.923 2.496c-.78.496-1.755.57-2.601.197l-3.859-1.703v18.673h10.383z"/></g><path d="m19.311 69.435c-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527v-16.693h31.054v16.693c0 8.576-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527z" fill="#facb35"/><path d="m50.365 69.435c-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527v-16.693h31.054v16.693c0 8.576-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527z" fill="#f9677f"/><path d="m81.419 69.435c-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527v-16.693h31.054v16.693c0 8.576-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527z" fill="#facb35"/><path d="m112.473 69.435c-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527v-16.693h31.054v16.693c0 8.576-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527z" fill="#f9677f"/><path d="m143.527 69.435c-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527v-16.693h31.054v16.693c0 8.576-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527z" fill="#facb35"/><path d="m174.581 69.435c-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527v-16.693h31.054v16.693c0 8.576-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527z" fill="#f9677f"/><path d="m205.635 69.435c-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527v-16.693h31.054v16.693c0 8.576-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527z" fill="#facb35"/><path d="m236.689 69.435c-8.575 0-15.527-6.952-15.527-15.527v-16.693h31.054v16.693c0 8.576-6.952 15.527-15.527 15.527z" fill="#f9677f"/><path d="m231.727 215.564h-208.495c-7.814 0-14.172-6.357-14.172-14.172v-18.662c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h231.838c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v18.662c0 7.815-6.357 14.172-14.171 14.172zm-217.666-30.334v16.162c0 5.058 4.114 9.172 9.172 9.172h208.494c5.058 0 9.172-4.114 9.172-9.172v-16.162z"/><path d="m165.729 255.998h-76.5c-4.241 0-7.691-3.45-7.691-7.691 0-4.24 3.45-7.69 7.691-7.69h76.5c4.241 0 7.691 3.45 7.691 7.69.001 4.241-3.449 7.691-7.691 7.691zm-76.5-10.382c-1.484 0-2.691 1.207-2.691 2.69 0 1.484 1.207 2.691 2.691 2.691h76.5c1.484 0 2.691-1.207 2.691-2.691 0-1.483-1.207-2.69-2.691-2.69z"/><path d="m153.272 245.616h-51.586c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-30.052c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h51.586c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v30.052c0 1.381-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5zm-49.085-5h46.586v-25.052h-46.586z"/><path d="m231.726 215.564h-208.494c-7.814 0-14.172-6.357-14.172-14.172v-134.043c0-.894.477-1.719 1.251-2.165.771-.447 1.727-.446 2.5.001 1.982 1.146 4.229 1.751 6.499 1.751 7.184 0 13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027 0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.026-5.844 13.026-13.027c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.026 13.027 7.184 0 13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027 0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.026-5.844 13.026-13.027c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.026 13.027 7.184 0 13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027 0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027 1.947 0 3.84-.436 5.626-1.294.774-.372 1.687-.32 2.414.137s1.169 1.257 1.169 2.116v133.498c.005 7.814-6.352 14.171-14.167 14.171zm-217.665-144.418v130.246c0 5.058 4.114 9.172 9.172 9.172h208.493c5.058 0 9.173-4.114 9.173-9.172v-129.958c-1.373.334-2.779.502-4.209.502-6.603 0-12.387-3.567-15.527-8.876-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.527 8.876s-12.386-3.567-15.526-8.876c-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.527 8.876s-12.387-3.567-15.527-8.876c-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.526 8.876-6.603 0-12.387-3.567-15.527-8.876-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.527 8.876s-12.386-3.567-15.526-8.876c-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.527 8.876s-12.387-3.567-15.527-8.876c-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.526 8.876-6.603 0-12.387-3.567-15.527-8.876-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.527 8.876-1.787 0-3.557-.269-5.255-.79z"/><path d="m19.311 71.936c-9.939 0-18.026-8.087-18.026-18.027v-16.694c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h31.054c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v16.693c-.001 9.941-8.088 18.028-18.028 18.028zm-13.027-32.221v14.193c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.026 13.027 7.184 0 13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027v-14.193z"/><path d="m50.365 71.936c-9.94 0-18.027-8.087-18.027-18.027v-16.694c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h31.054c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v16.693c0 9.941-8.087 18.028-18.027 18.028zm-13.027-32.221v14.193c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.026-5.844 13.026-13.027v-14.193z"/><path d="m81.419 71.936c-9.94 0-18.027-8.087-18.027-18.027v-16.694c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h31.055c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v16.693c-.001 9.941-8.088 18.028-18.028 18.028zm-13.027-32.221v14.193c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027v-14.193z"/><path d="m112.473 71.936c-9.939 0-18.026-8.087-18.026-18.027v-16.694c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h31.053c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v16.693c0 9.941-8.087 18.028-18.027 18.028zm-13.027-32.221v14.193c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.026 13.027 7.184 0 13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027v-14.193z"/><path d="m143.527 71.936c-9.94 0-18.027-8.087-18.027-18.027v-16.694c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h31.054c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v16.693c0 9.941-8.087 18.028-18.027 18.028zm-13.027-32.221v14.193c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.026-5.844 13.026-13.027v-14.193z"/><path d="m174.581 71.936c-9.94 0-18.027-8.087-18.027-18.027v-16.694c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h31.055c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v16.693c-.001 9.941-8.088 18.028-18.028 18.028zm-13.027-32.221v14.193c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027v-14.193z"/><path d="m205.635 71.936c-9.939 0-18.026-8.087-18.026-18.027v-16.694c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h31.054c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v16.693c-.001 9.941-8.088 18.028-18.028 18.028zm-13.027-32.221v14.193c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.026 13.027 7.184 0 13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027v-14.193z"/><path d="m236.689 71.936c-9.94 0-18.027-8.087-18.027-18.027v-16.694c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h31.054c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v16.693c0 9.941-8.087 18.028-18.027 18.028zm-13.027-32.221v14.193c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.026-5.844 13.026-13.027v-14.193z"/><path d="m34.838 39.711h-31.054c-.924 0-1.772-.51-2.207-1.325-.434-.815-.383-1.804.133-2.57l16.484-24.497c.588-.872 1.659-1.282 2.678-1.03.264.065.47.096.651.096h25.592c.868 0 1.674.45 2.129 1.189s.494 1.662.103 2.437l-12.278 24.326c-.424.843-1.288 1.374-2.231 1.374zm-26.359-5h24.819l9.754-19.327h-21.529c-.013 0-.025 0-.038 0z"/><path d="m65.892 39.711h-31.054c-.868 0-1.674-.45-2.129-1.189s-.494-1.662-.103-2.437l12.277-24.327c.425-.843 1.288-1.374 2.231-1.374h26.962c.805 0 1.561.388 2.03 1.041s.596 1.493.339 2.256l-8.186 24.327c-.34 1.017-1.294 1.703-2.367 1.703zm-26.992-5h25.194l6.504-19.327h-21.944z"/><path d="m96.946 39.711h-31.054c-.805 0-1.561-.388-2.03-1.041s-.596-1.493-.339-2.256l8.186-24.327c.342-1.018 1.296-1.703 2.369-1.703h26.961c.735 0 1.434.324 1.909.886s.678 1.304.557 2.029l-4.092 24.327c-.204 1.203-1.246 2.085-2.467 2.085zm-27.576-5h25.462l3.25-19.327h-22.208z"/><path d="m128 39.711h-31.054c-.735 0-1.434-.324-1.909-.886s-.678-1.304-.557-2.029l4.092-24.327c.203-1.203 1.245-2.085 2.466-2.085h26.962c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v24.327c0 1.381-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5zm-28.098-5h25.598v-19.327h-22.348z"/><path d="m159.054 39.711h-31.054c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-24.327c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h26.962c1.221 0 2.263.882 2.466 2.085l4.092 24.327c.121.726-.082 1.468-.557 2.029-.476.562-1.174.886-1.909.886zm-28.554-5h25.598l-3.25-19.327h-22.348z"/><path d="m190.108 39.711h-31.055c-1.221 0-2.263-.882-2.466-2.085l-4.092-24.327c-.121-.726.082-1.468.557-2.029.476-.562 1.174-.886 1.909-.886h26.962c1.073 0 2.027.686 2.369 1.703l8.185 24.327c.257.763.131 1.603-.339 2.256s-1.225 1.041-2.03 1.041zm-28.94-5h25.462l-6.503-19.327h-22.209z"/><path d="m221.162 39.711h-31.054c-1.073 0-2.027-.686-2.369-1.703l-8.185-24.327c-.257-.763-.131-1.603.339-2.256s1.226-1.041 2.03-1.041h26.961c.943 0 1.807.531 2.231 1.374l12.277 24.327c.392.774.353 1.697-.103 2.437s-1.259 1.189-2.127 1.189zm-29.257-5h25.195l-9.754-19.327h-21.943z"/><path d="m252.216 39.711h-31.054c-.943 0-1.807-.531-2.231-1.374l-12.278-24.327c-.392-.774-.353-1.697.103-2.437s1.261-1.189 2.129-1.189h24.55c.367 0 .729-.077 1.077-.229 1.076-.473 2.455-.083 3.113.895l16.665 24.767c.516.767.566 1.755.133 2.57-.435.814-1.283 1.324-2.207 1.324zm-29.515-5h24.819l-13.052-19.397c-.342.047-.687.07-1.034.07h-20.487z"/><path d="m232.787 185.23h-210.616c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-113.569c0-1.204.858-2.236 2.041-2.458 6.157-1.148 10.626-6.529 10.626-12.795 0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.026-5.844 13.026-13.027c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.026 13.027 7.184 0 13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027 0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.026-5.844 13.026-13.027c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.027 13.027s13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 7.184 5.844 13.027 13.026 13.027 7.184 0 13.027-5.844 13.027-13.027 0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5c0 5.925 4.011 11.104 9.753 12.593 1.103.286 1.872 1.281 1.872 2.42v113.81c.004 1.38-1.115 2.499-2.496 2.499zm-208.116-5h205.616v-109.485c-3.893-1.476-7.079-4.224-9.125-7.687-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.877-15.527 8.877s-12.386-3.567-15.526-8.876c-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.527 8.876s-12.387-3.567-15.527-8.876c-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.526 8.876-6.603 0-12.387-3.567-15.527-8.876-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.527 8.876s-12.386-3.567-15.526-8.876c-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.527 8.876s-12.387-3.567-15.527-8.876c-3.141 5.309-8.925 8.876-15.526 8.876s-12.386-3.566-15.526-8.874c-2.233 3.781-5.82 6.703-10.168 8.052v109.117z"/><path d="m214.353 159.374h-22.882c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5s1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h22.882c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5s-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m170.5 159.374h-121c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5s1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h121c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5s-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m214.353 111.794h-22.882c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5s1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h22.882c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5s-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m214.353 95.934h-22.882c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5s1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h22.882c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5s-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m65.353 87.934h-22.882c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5s1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h22.882c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5s-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m214.353 127.654h-22.882c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5s1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h22.882c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5s-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m214.353 143.514h-22.882c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5s1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5h22.882c1.381 0 2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5s-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m54.5 164c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-60c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v60c0 1.381-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m71.5 169.147c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-1.57c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v1.57c0 1.381-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m93.5 169.147c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-1.57c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v1.57c0 1.381-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m116.5 169.147c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-1.57c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v1.57c0 1.381-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m138.5 169.147c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-1.57c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v1.57c0 1.381-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m161.5 169.147c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-1.57c0-1.381 1.119-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.119 2.5 2.5v1.57c0 1.381-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5z"/><path d="m166.5 159.374h-112c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-23.874c0-.845.427-1.633 1.135-2.095s1.603-.534 2.374-.192l15.647 6.903c.081.035.177.027.25-.02l19.404-12.349c1.582-1.007 3.599-1.093 5.262-.227l19.701 10.279c.106.056.237.033.318-.056l20.095-21.921c.585-.639 1.33-1.128 2.151-1.414l25.483-9.107c1.184-.423 2.506-.246 3.535.479s1.644 1.909 1.644 3.168v50.424c.001 1.383-1.118 2.502-2.499 2.502zm-109.5-5h107v-46.325l-23.999 8.577c-.062.021-.1.046-.128.076l-20.096 21.922c-1.609 1.756-4.206 2.213-6.317 1.109l-19.7-10.278c-.085-.046-.187-.04-.265.011l-19.405 12.35c-1.488.944-3.34 1.085-4.95.376l-12.14-5.357zm108.507-46.864c-.001 0 0 0 0 0zm-.843-2.354h.01z"/><path d="m166.5 159.374h-10.212c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-48.725c0-1.057.664-1.999 1.659-2.354l8.374-2.992c1.184-.423 2.506-.246 3.535.479s1.644 1.909 1.644 3.168v50.424c0 1.381-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5zm-7.712-5h5.212v-46.325l-5.212 1.862zm6.718-46.863h-.002zm-.842-2.355h.01z"/><path d="m144.17 159.374h-10.382c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-37.233c0-.625.234-1.229.657-1.689l4.241-4.627c.585-.639 1.33-1.128 2.151-1.414l4.99-1.784c.768-.272 1.617-.157 2.281.311.665.469 1.061 1.23 1.061 2.044v44.394c.001 1.379-1.118 2.498-2.499 2.498zm-7.882-5h5.382v-38.345l-1.669.597c-.062.021-.1.046-.128.076l-3.585 3.911z"/><path d="m121.67 159.374h-10.382c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-21.093c0-.874.456-1.685 1.204-2.138s1.678-.482 2.452-.079l3.329 1.736c.106.056.237.033.318-.056l3.735-4.075c.695-.759 1.786-1.013 2.749-.641.961.374 1.594 1.299 1.594 2.33v24.015c.001 1.382-1.118 2.501-2.499 2.501zm-7.882-5h5.382v-15.184c-1.513 1.201-3.59 1.485-5.382.7z"/><path d="m99.17 159.374h-10.382c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-27.376c0-.854.437-1.65 1.158-2.109l3.364-2.141c1.582-1.007 3.599-1.093 5.262-.227l4.255 2.222c.825.431 1.343 1.284 1.343 2.216v27.415c0 1.381-1.119 2.5-2.5 2.5zm-7.882-5h5.382v-23.4l-2.911-1.52c-.085-.044-.186-.039-.264.012l-2.207 1.404z"/><path d="m76.67 159.374h-10.382c-1.381 0-2.5-1.119-2.5-2.5v-18.673c0-.845.427-1.633 1.135-2.095s1.603-.534 2.374-.192l3.859 1.702c.081.035.177.027.25-.02l3.921-2.496c.771-.489 1.745-.521 2.546-.082.8.438 1.297 1.279 1.297 2.191v19.664c0 1.382-1.119 2.501-2.5 2.501zm-7.882-5h5.382v-12.609l-.079.051c-1.488.944-3.338 1.086-4.951.376l-.352-.155z"/><path d="m127.479 205.059c-4.241 0-7.691-3.45-7.691-7.691s3.45-7.691 7.691-7.691c4.24 0 7.69 3.45 7.69 7.691s-3.449 7.691-7.69 7.691zm0-10.383c-1.484 0-2.691 1.207-2.691 2.691s1.207 2.691 2.691 2.691c1.483 0 2.69-1.207 2.69-2.691s-1.206-2.691-2.69-2.691z"/></svg>
      </div>
  </td>
    <td>this is the description area</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

**Css**

```
table{
  width:100%;

}

.icon svg{
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
    }

table tr td:first-child{
  width:50px;
}

table tr td:last-child{
  width:calc(100% - 50px);
}
```